# ServiceStack.Redis searching cache

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, caching, redis

I have been using ServiceStack.Redis for a couple of days and the last puzzle in my app is searching cache.

I have a simple object

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
}
```

e.g. I want to return all persons which Name is Joe and they are older than 10 years

What is better speed wise?

1. To run query against database which will return a list of ids and than to get matched records via Redis .GetByIds function.

or

2. As RedisClient doesn't have native Linq support (doesn't have AsEnumerable only iList) to run GetAll() and than to preform further filtering.

Does anyone have experience with this ?

Comment: What's best speed wise?  I suspect that if you profile each a few thousand times you'll find out what is best for your application structure and data set.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with same problem, my option was to save a "light " set of data that represents the attributes I need to identify a whole register o attributes I need to filter the whole bunch of data, then go to the database for the rest if necessary.

I just started to use redis and I know this probably is not the best option but its better than go to the database each time even for filtering information.

Hope to know if you found a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Redis is not a good candidate for such queries, it doesn't have indexes, so you might end up building your own in order to meet speed requirements. Which is not a good idea at all. 
So I would go with a SQL db which can help me on such queries, or even more complex ones on the Person type.
And then you can use the Redis cache only to store the query results in it so you can easy move through them for things like paging or sorting.
At least this is how we do it in our apps.